# Office 365 API - Automatic Login

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller, exchange-server, office365

In these examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/starter-projects-and-code-samples the user has to sign in their respective Office 365 account to have access to their email and calendar.

Is it possible to make an automatic sign in process with known username and password and prevent from logging in every time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, the user has to log in at some point and consent to the app's requested access. However, once they've done that, you can cache the access token and refresh token. The user would only have to re-enter their username and password if your refresh token expired.